# Why when I return back from login to I get an ERROR with the sample app?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, sample

This is in regards to the sample: msal-web-sample-0.1.0

I am using tomcat 9 and maven to build and run the msal-web-sample code. It is building fine and running, loading spring, etc. I am able to go out and get a username and passowrd login. However, when it tries to return back to my system (https://localhost:8443/msal4jsample/secure/aad) it just has a bit "ERROR PAGE!" heading with  Home Page link going back to the main tomcat page.

In the tomcat runtime it has:
2021-06-29 15:28:06.108 ERROR 6360 --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Cannot forward to error page for request [/secure/aad] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

Of course, that doesn't apply to my setup.
I see the get in the logs returning back OK and don't see any errors on startup. I am at a loss as to where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Also, is there a non-spring implementation that can be used with java but still using MSAL?

Thanks
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Please share additional information about the error. Do you have trouble regrading AAD? Check your environmental settings (Tomcat) if this isn't the case.

Comment: I have actually moved on from this project so don't have anything setup anymore. I believe Apache settings were OK, as other things work fine. I know, my colleague who is now working on this had the same issues with the sample code. There are some bugs in there. The Spring, question, I thought about later really was just this example used Spring, we don't need it for the actual implementation.